# View.OnClickListener in a custom DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-view, onclicklistener, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to implement a custom `DialogFragment`, following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog) tutorial. My problem is that I fail to handle my custom's view's button.setOnClickListener event. The strangest part is that I have no problem in geting the `.getText()` of my button, I just can't find a way to handle the click event. Bellow is my code:

SettingsDialogFragment.java

```
 public class SettingsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null);

    final Button colorButton =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.colorButton_dialogSettings);
    String s = colorButton.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("its working "+s);

    //NOT working
    colorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("OnClick");
        }
    });

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    SettingsDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

`
My custom view code (dialog_settings.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#00CCCC"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/dialog_settings_title"
    android:id="@+id/editText"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/colorButton_dialogSettings"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/color_picker_title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stroke"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonStroke"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/colorButton_dialogSettings"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fill"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton_fill"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/colorButton_dialogSettings"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButtonStroke"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButtonStroke"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />
```

Comment: Try changing to `colorButton.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`

Comment: I cannot use `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` since `DialogFragment` does not implement it [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am just showing you the important part.. i hope you find their respective lines in your code

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null);
// inflating your view..for drawback, this line is [A]
```

your `colorButton` has a reference to `view.findViewById(R.id.colorButton_dialogSettings)` which is from the viewgroup `view`..which you reference an onclick listener for it..

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null))
```

this code right here sets the content view for your dialog. it inflates a the layout and does it's work.. so in the end your `builder` is not referencing it's *content view* to `view` but a new inflated `R.layout.dialog_settings` layout..

**so to solve it** just do this

```
builder.setView(view) // hope you know the view parameter
```

the `view` is what you instantiated at line [A] ..

Hope i made sense, and lucid enough for you..let me know if it helps

Comment: I can't believe I was missing this one... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**

Change your `onCreateDialog` to this:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 

public class SettingsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements onClickListener
{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null);

    final Button colorButton =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.colorButton_dialogSettings);
    String s = colorButton.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("its working "+s);

    colorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.colorButton_dialogSettings
                    System.out.println("OnClick");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
        }
    });

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    SettingsDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

In your activity:

`private Button colorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colorButton_dialogSettings);`

**Old answer that requires you to write your own [showDialog method*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog)*

Try deleting your button code in the onCreateDialog and add this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        Button colorButton =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.colorButton_dialogSettings);
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
                ((FragmentDialog)getActivity()).showDialog();
                System.out.println("OnClick");
            }
        });

        return v;
```